# Trying to pass a STL list<string> as an argument to a class in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, arguments

I am coding a version of hangman as an assignment, and I am already confused about the directions as it is. But none the less, I want to pass an STL list to a function of a class that I have created. In order to print my hangman in different states, e.g. head, body, left arm etc.here is the majority of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "slot.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string head[4] = {"\t\t  *****", "\t\t  *  *", "\t\t  *  *", 
                      "\t\t  *****"};

    string body[10] = {"\t\t  *****", "\t\t  *   *", "\t\t  *   *", 
                       "\t\t  *****", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |",
                       "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |"};

    string leftarm[10] = {"\t\t  *****", "\t\t  *   *", "\t\t  *   *", 
                          "\t\t  *****", "\t\t\\  |", "\t\t \\ |",
                          "\t\t  \\|", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |"};

    string rightarm[10] = {"\t\t  *****", "\t\t  *   *", "\t\t  *   *", 
                           "\t\t  *****", "\t\t \\  |  /", "\t\t  \\ | /",
                           "\t\t   \\|/", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |", 
                           "\t\t    |"};

    string leftleg[13] = {"\t\t  *****", "\t\t  *   *", "\t\t  *   *", 
                          "\t\t  *****", "\t\t \\  |  /", "\t\t  \\ | /",
                          "\t\t   \\|/", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |", 
                          "\t\t    |", "\t\t   /", "\t\t  /", "\t\t /",};

    string rightleg[13] = {"\t\t  *****", "\t\t  *   *", "\t\t  *   *", 
                           "\t\t  *****", "\t\t \\  |  /", "\t\t  \\ | /",
                           "\t\t   \\|/", "\t\t    |", "\t\t    |",
                           "\t\t    |", 
                           "\t\t   / \\",
                           "\t\t  /   \\",
                           "\t\t /     \\",};

    string holdword = "";
    list<string> hanglist;

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        holdword = head[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        holdword = body[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        holdword = leftarm[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        holdword = rightarm[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        holdword = leftleg[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        holdword = rightleg[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }


    DisplayHangman(hanglist);

    Slot temp;
    temp.DisplayHang(hanglist);

    hanglist.clear(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the class and the header file:

```
//********************************************
// This slot.cpp class is designed and created
// to supply the appropriate observer and
// mutator methods.
//********************************************
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include "slot.h"

using namespace std;

Slot::Slot()
{
    list<string> holdlist(60);
}

void DisplayHangman(list<string>& hanglist) {

    holdlist = hanglist;

    string hangword = "";

    int lstsize = 0;

    lstsize += hanglist.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < lstsize; i++) {

        string diphang = holdlist.front();
        holdlist.pop_front();
        hangword = diphang;
        cout << hangword << endl;
        hangword = "";
    }
    lstsize = 0; 
    holdlist.clear();

}
Slot::~Slot() {}
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Slot
{
public:
    Slot();

    void DisplayHangman(list<string>& hanglist);
    private:
       list<string> holdlist(60);

};
Slot::~Slot()
```

I am so frustrated, I literally punched a desk and fractured my hand!
Is this even a logical what I am trying to do?

To pass a list as a parameter to a function that has been abstracted from another class?

I am just trying to unit test it.

Comment: And what is a question?

Comment: Rollbacked edits that break the question.

Answer (score 0):

- `DisplayHangman` and `slot` used in `main()` isn't declared.
- The class `Slot` doesn't have member `DisplayHang`.
- There is a meaningless declaration and initialization of local variable in `Slot:Slot()`.
- `void DisplayHangman(list<string>& hanglist)` in `slot.cpp` isn't a definition of member function.
- `(60)` in the header will emit compile error.
- `list` and `string` that are used in the header file are not declared.
- `Slot::~Slot()` in the header file isn't where it should be.

Corrected codes:

last part of `main()` function:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        holdword = rightleg[j];
        hanglist.push_back(holdword);
        holdword = "";
    }

    Slot temp;
    temp.DisplayHangman(hanglist);

    hanglist.clear(); 
    return 0;
}
```

function definitions in `slot.cpp`:

```
Slot::Slot() : holdlist(60)
{
}

void Slot::DisplayHangman(list<string>& hanglist) {

    // implementation should be same as the original, omitted

}
Slot::~Slot() {}
```

the header file:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Slot
{
public:
    Slot();
    ~Slot();

    void DisplayHangman(std::list<std::string>& hanglist);
    private:
       std::list<std::string> holdlist;

};
```

Comment: Thanks Mike!! I decided to pass the list by value instead by reference and go with an empty constructor, instead of initializing copying hanglist to holdlist. I also had to add using namespace std to the slot implementation file or else it won't compile. I figured it would compile if the using namespace std prototype is in the driver class but it wouldn't. Is that because the list being altered by the Slot class is in the STL?